# How to create JSON object from primitive type in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have entity with some data, that has field `price`.

I have method that gets price sum of all items. 
How should I implement controller method to GET it in Json, if this method returns Double?

```
@GetMapping("/sum")
    public ResponseEntity<Double> getSum(){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(productService.getSum());
    }
```

With this method I receive number without JSON structure in response.

Assume we have: 123456.0

But we need:

```
{
  "sum" : 123456.0
}
```

Comment: Create a class with a property named sum, of type double. And return a ResponseEntity<ThatClass>.

Comment: @JBNizet So is it only one way to do that?

Comment: You can use a Map also.

Comment: It's the obvious, trivial, common way. There might be other ways, but why not use that one?

Comment: @JBNizet And as I understood, I dont need ResponseEntity, if I expect Status = OK? Because even without this class I am getting STATUS:200

Comment: Indeed, you can return an instance of ThatClass directly.

Comment: @JBNizet I thought that it is stupid way to create new class for that

Comment: @JBNizet so ResponseEntity is usefull for all other http codes except 200 ?

Comment: No, it's not. The class is simple? That's a good thing: simple is good. And if you ever have to return additional values (aferage, percentiles, whatever), then you'll add properties to that class.

Comment: @JBNizet Cool thank you for advice

Comment: ResponseEntity is useful when you want to return other status codes dynamically (if it's always the same, then you can use the ResponseStatus annotation), or when you want to add headers, or set a content type, etc. Look at its javadoc.

Comment: @JBNizet in design problem, how do you think, class ProductPriceSum should be DTO class?

Comment: Yes, it's a DTO, since it' purpose is to transport Data.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ThatCustomClass {
 BigDecimal sum;
}
```

There are different methods to do that. Arranged in the descending order of my preference

1. Respond with a `ResponseEntity<ThatCustomClass>`

   @JBNizet already explained this
2. Respond with ThatCustomClass. Then use controllerAdvices and Exceptions for sending anything other than 200
3. Use a HashMap instead of a DTO
4. Use String manipulation to create JSON string (I don't even know why I listed this option here)

BTW, for currency operations don't use Double/Float, use BigDecimal instead http://java-performance.info/bigdecimal-vs-double-in-financial-calculations/

Comment: Oh really, I could use Maps... Thanks) And Why controllerAdvice? I use just @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND) for example, under custom Exception class

Comment: @andrew17, yes, you are right, Annotating CustomExceptions is one way to do it. 
But if you want to send 400 for an exception coming from HibernateValidator (Basically any other exception type that you didnt create) or 
you want to do something else such as logging and you dont want that situate along with your business logic, you can use controllerAdvice instead.